# Get number of occurrences of each unique value

Tags: r, dplyr

This is something I spent some time searching for. There were several good answers on Stack Overflow detailing how you can get the number of unique values, but I couldn't find any that showed how to count the number of occurrences for each value using `dplyr`.

Comment: `dplyr` does *not* disable *base*: `table(df$val)`

Comment: `table(df$val)` doesn't provide the number of occurrences of each variable? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Oh yes it does. It gives for 0 3 times, for 1 4 times, for 2 2 times and for 3 1 time.

Comment: Oh, now I see how to interpret it! Thank you very much, that is much more compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df %>% select(val) %>% group_by(val) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% unique()
```

This first filters out the value of interest, groups by it, then creates a new column all the unique values, and the number of occurrences of each of those values.

Here is a reproducible example showcasing how it works:

```r
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)
val <- c(0,1,2,3,1,1,1,0,0,2)
df <- data.frame(id=id,val=val)
df
#>    id val
#> 1   1   0
#> 2   2   1
#> 3   3   2
#> 4   4   3
#> 5   5   1
#> 6   6   1
#> 7   7   1
#> 8   8   0
#> 9   9   0
#> 10  0   2

df %>% select(val) %>% group_by(val) %>% mutate(count = n()) %>% unique()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#> # Groups:   val [4]
#>     val count
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     0     3
#> 2     1     4
#> 3     2     2
#> 4     3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>